# Example of rational jumps in upper ramification filtration

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

Can anyone point to me or write down an explicit example of a non-integer jump of the higher ramification filtration in positive characteristic and the corresponding equations of the intermediate extensions? Obviously the Galois group will not be Abelian.

It would be appreciated if any source of examples can be found.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. What do you mean with non-integer jump? Can you illustrate it with the splitting field of $X^3-t^3 X-t \in \Bbb{F}_3((t))[X]$, a totally ramified degree 6 extension.

Comment: I am looking for an example where the theorem of Hasse - Arf (see below) fails, i.e. a non-abelian extension given in an explicit way so I can understand things.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Arf_theorem